# Weird arch shape rendered whenever an "s" or "c" is followed by a "t" or "p" on iPad

Tags: html, css, ipad, fonts

Whenever there is an "st" or a "ct" there is a super weird arch that comes up, spanning from the top of the "c"/"s" and looping up and over to descend upon the "t". This really won't make sense without a picture.

Screenshot with lots of examples of the problem :

[image]

And the fonts:

```
style.css
12:    font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
17:    font-family: "TTNorms";
25:    font-family: "TTNorms-bold";
33:    font-family: "NoeDisplay-Bold";
41:    font-family: 'TTNorms', arial, sans-serif;
46:    font-family: 'TTNorms-bold', arial, sans-serif;
51:    font-family: 'NoeDisplay-Bold', 'Times New Roman', Serif !important;
93:    font-family: 'TTNorms-bold', arial, sans-serif;
110:    font-family: 'TTNorms', arial, sans-serif;
223:    font-family: 'TT Norms', Arial, Sans-Serif;
312:    font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
628:    font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
942:    font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
1006:    font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
1474:    font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
1530:    font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
1578:    font-family: #083B36;
1846:    font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
```

Comment: It seems the problem is the font. Scroll here to the picture 'Ligatures'. https://weandthecolor.com/tt-norms-font-family-typetype/87559
Why do you use so many fonts? Try only Roboto and see if the problem still exists.

Comment: What encoding do you use?

Comment: Can you find out which font is actually being used? (Use your browser's dev tools inspect factility). It does look strange that fonts are being called so much, and I specially don't understand the one on line 1578 which looks like a hex color code.

Comment: CSS has a property for adjusting/disabling ligatures. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-variant-ligatures

Comment: @Azu I didn't write this, it's an artifact from an old teammate

Comment: definitely ligatures in the font, not an encoding issue